# Local Notification in iOS + Titanium

Tags: iphone, notifications, titanium

I am using Titanium for setting Local Notification. All I am getting is fine.I am setting 10 notifications for coming 10 days with static time like 11 AM. I am not using repeat function, because all the day, message will be different. Problem is that, I am getting only 5 notification. Remaining 5 not fired. I am doing this with same day.
Now, when I changed it on daily basis, like today 11AM, tomorrow 11AM, ....
Installed app on device.Change the device date as tomorrow and time as 10:55AM. But after 5 min, I am not getting any notification.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you provide some code?